# Variables with different significance levels in linear model (model interpretation)

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, linear-model

What is the correct interpretation in (multiple) linear regression model when independent variables have different levels of significance?

For example, in the regression below the variable $X$ was significant at 0.001, but the intercept was significant just at 0.1.

I am not sure if I made myself clear, but saying in other words:
Is the intercept weakening the model?
Should I say the model is significant at 0.1 level (based on the smaller value)?

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3182 -0.5247  0.1119  0.4472  1.5385 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   6.0456     3.1173   1.939   0.0667 .  
X             0.6957     0.1169   5.950 8.09e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.9465 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.639,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.6209 
F-statistic:  35.4 on 1 and 20 DF,  p-value: 8.087e-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intercept-only model is the 'null' model here, and the p-value associated with the model overall is given in the last line of your output.

You may notice it's the same as for the slope coefficient; that's because it's being compared to an intercept-only model.

You should definitely not regard including the intercept as 'weakening' your model. It isn't.

Since your question asks about multiple regression:

> What is the correct interpretation in (multiple) linear regression model when independent variables have different level of significance?

you should probably include an example that actually has two variables in it.

In general, the above comment (that the p-value of the model overall is given in the last line of that `lm` output) applies to multiple regression.

How you treat the various p-values in your output and what you want to do with variables that are not significant depends on the purpose of your analysis - what questions you are trying to address.
......

Comment: Thank's @Glen. Unfortunately, I do not have one example regarding multiple linear regression.